# How to update table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I am trying to update the rows of the below html table dynamically based on the input received from ajax request made which returns a JSON object.

If i get more than one json object it becomes an issue to print it on the web page. I am looking at possible best solutions in this case to dynamically update my table using jQuery? For example If i get 10 objects I only want to show 5 and the rest maybe a next page link ? Can someone guide me what should i look into ?

jQuery Ajax

```
<script>
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/getData/USSOUTH/',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {

                for (var i in data) {

                    var USERNAME = data[i].USERNAME;
                    var EMAIL = data[i].EMAIL;
                    var PASSWORD = data[i].PASSWORD;
                    var ACTIVE = data[i].ACTIVE;

                }
            }
        });
</script>
```

HTML BODY

```
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="table">

    <div class="row header blue">
      <div class="cell">
        Username
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Email
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Password
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Active
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        ninjalug
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        misterninja@hotmail.com
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        ************
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Yes
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: If you only want the next 5 entries, why not include that parameter in the request, and have it return just those? Or add them all, but hide the last 5, and include a button to show them?

Comment: I pray that you've salted and hashed your plain text passwords.

Answer (score 3):

i kinda simplified the code, but you'll get the gist and can modify it to apply with your specific code (and i cant do json with code snippet, so i simulated an array variable called `jsonData`)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var jsonData = [
        { 'name': 'name2', 'email':'email2', 'content':'content2' },
        { 'name': 'name3', 'email':'email3', 'content':'content3' },
        { 'name': 'name4', 'email':'email4', 'content':'content4' },
        { 'name': 'name5', 'email':'email5', 'content':'content5' },
        { 'name': 'name6', 'email':'email6', 'content':'content6' },
        { 'name': 'name7', 'email':'email7', 'content':'content7' },
        { 'name': 'name8', 'email':'email8', 'content':'content8' }
    ];
    $('.add').on('click', function() {
        console.log('click');
        var length = jsonData.length;
        if (length > 5 ) { length = 5; } //limit to 5
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var clone = $('#template').clone(true).attr('id', '');
            clone.find('.name').html(jsonData[i]['name']);
            clone.find('.email').html(jsonData[i]['email']);
            clone.find('.content').html(jsonData[i]['content']);
            clone.appendTo('table');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
td {
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="add">add</a>
<table>
    <tr id="template" class="dataRow">
        <td class="name">Name1</td>
        <td class="email">Email1</td>
        <td class="content">Content1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You solution needs part for record navigation. But one up for fast response.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the AJAX service documentation if it supports paging, which is its respond will contain only 5 records and an indicator that there is some more. That way you will be able to request next 5 records to display if needed in similar way as your first request.

If the service does not support paging then you may hide any record above first 5, with attribute `style="display: none;"` and display navigation links NEXT & PREVIOUS to "scroll" results.

```js
// Data will be replaced with your Json call
var data = [
  {'username': 'name1', 'email':'email1', 'password':'password1', 'active':'active1' },
  {'username': 'name2', 'email':'email2', 'password':'password2', 'active':'active2' },
  {'username': 'name3', 'email':'email3', 'password':'password3', 'active':'active3' },
  {'username': 'name4', 'email':'email4', 'password':'password4', 'active':'active4' },
  {'username': 'name5', 'email':'email5', 'password':'password5', 'active':'active5' },
  {'username': 'name6', 'email':'email6', 'password':'password6', 'active':'active6' },
  {'username': 'name7', 'email':'email7', 'password':'password7', 'active':'active7' },
  {'username': 'name8', 'email':'email8', 'password':'password8', 'active':'active8' },
  {'username': 'name9', 'email':'email9', 'password':'password9', 'active':'active9' },
  {'username': 'name10','email':'email10','password':'password10','active':'active10'},
  {'username': 'name11','email':'email11','password':'password11','active':'active11'},
  {'username': 'name12','email':'email12','password':'password12','active':'active12'}
];

var MAX_ROWS = 5;
var totalRows = 0;
var page = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  // display first 5 rows
  var $templateRow = $('#templateRow');
  $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
    var $row = $templateRow.clone().removeAttr('id')
    // copy data
    $row.find('*[data-name]').html(obj.username);
    $row.find('*[data-email]').html(obj.email);
    $row.find('*[data-pass]').html(obj.password);
    $row.find('*[data-active]').html(obj.active);
    $('.table').append($row);
  });
  // Navigation part
  page = 0;
  totalRows = data.length;
  showRows();
  displayNext();

  // Navigation handler
  $('*[data-prev-lnk]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    page--;
    displayPrev();
    displayNext();
    showRows()
  });

  $('*[data-next-lnk]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    page++;
    displayPrev();
    displayNext();
    showRows();
  });
});

function displayPrev() {
  if (page > 0)
    $('*[data-prev-lnk]').show();
  else
    $('*[data-prev-lnk]').hide();
}

function displayNext() {
  var currRow = (page+1) * MAX_ROWS;
  if (currRow >= totalRows)
    $('*[data-next-lnk]').hide();
  else
    $('*[data-next-lnk]').show();
}

function showRows() {
  var startRow = page * MAX_ROWS;
  var counter = 0;
  $('.row').each( function() {
    if (! ($(this).attr('id') || $(this).hasClass('header'))) {
      if (counter < startRow || counter >= startRow + MAX_ROWS) {
        $(this).hide();
      }
      else {
        $(this).show();
      }
      counter++;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
div.table {border: 1px solid black; display: table; width: 500px;}
div.row {border: 1px solid black; display: table-row; }
div.cell {border: 1px solid black; display: table-cell; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row header blue">
      <div class="cell">Username</div>
      <div class="cell">Email</div>
      <div class="cell">Password</div>
      <div class="cell">Active</div>
    </div>
    <div id="templateRow" class="row" style="display:none;">
      <div class="cell" data-name=''></div>
      <div class="cell" data-email=''></div>
      <div class="cell" data-pass=''></div>
      <div class="cell" data-active=''></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/><a href='#' data-prev-lnk='' style='display:none'>Previous</a>
  <br/><a href='#' data-next-lnk='' style='display:none'>Next</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use `thead` and `tbody` for better usage and add button for next set of results.

HTML:

```
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

  <button id ="nextPage" value ="Next page">
  <div class="table">
    <thead class="row header blue">
      <div class="cell">
        Username
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Email
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Password
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Active
      </div>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        ninjalug
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        misterninja@hotmail.com
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        ************
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Yes
      </div>
    </div>
    </tbody>

  </div>

</div>

</body>
```

in JS assign function to button, which will display next 5 records:

```
var results = "";
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/getData/USSOUTH/',
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        results = data;
        showResults(results);

    }
});

//function for showing results
function showResults(data)
{
    var rows = $('tbody .row').length; // get number of already displayed records
    for (i = rows; i<=from+4,i++;) //add next 5 records
    {
        var content = '\
            <div class="row">\
                <div class="cell">\
                    '+data[i].USERNAME+'\
                </div>\
                <div class="cell">\
                    '+data[i].EMAIL+'\
                </div>\
                <div class="cell">\
                    '+data[i].PASSWORD+'\
                </div>\
                <div class="cell">\
                    '+data[i].ACTIVE+'\
                </div>\
            </div>';
        $('tbody .row:last').after(content);
    }
}

$("nextPage").click(function(){
    showResults(results);
});
```