# Pagination in Java using JS/jQuery/AJAX and controllers

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring, pagination

I have such issue: I need to implement pagination on my jsp. I'm using jQuery DataTable, but I want to have my own pagination. I have controller that return me page and controller that returns me number of elements in DB.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/all-events", params = { "page", "size" }, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<EventDto> getAllEventsPaging(
        @RequestParam(value = "page") Integer page,
        @RequestParam(value = "size") Integer size) {
    List<EventDto> events = eventService.getAllEventsPaging(page, size);
    return events;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/paging",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAllEventsPaging(@RequestParam("size") Long size,Model model) {
    Long dataBaseSize = eventRepository.count();
    Long amount;
    if (dataBaseSize % size == 0){
        amount = dataBaseSize % size;
    } else{
        amount = dataBaseSize % size + 1;
    }
    model.addAttribute("amount", amount);
    return "amount";
}
```

Then I have js file that build table:

```
$(document)
    .ready(
            function() {
                size = $(
                        "#request_table_obtain_length option:selected")
                        .val();
                table = $("table.table-bordered")
                        .dataTable(
                                {
                                    "sAjaxDataProp" : "",
                                    "fnInitComplete" : function(settings,
                                            json) {
                                    },
                                    "fnRowCallback" : function(nRow, aData,
                                            iDisplayIndex,
                                            iDisplayIndexFull) {
                                        var ul = $("<ul/>", {
                                            'class' : "dropdown-menu"
                                        });
                                        var li = $("<li/>");
                                        var div = $("<div/>", {
                                            "class" : "input-group-btn"
                                        });
                                    },


                                    "bProcessing" : false,
                                    "bServerSide" : false,
                                    "bPaginate" : false,
                                    "bFilter" : false,
                                    "bInfo" : false,
                                    "sAjaxSource" : "all-events?page="
                                            + page + "&size=" + size,
                                    "aoColumns" : [
                                            {
                                                "mData" : function(data,
                                                        type, full) {
                                                    return '<a href=event?id='
                                                            + data.id
                                                            + '>'
                                                            + data.name
                                                            + '</a>';
                                                }

                                            },
                                            {
                                                "mData" : "startDate",
                                                "mRender" : function(data,
                                                        type, full) {
                                                    return new Date(data)
                                                            .toLocaleString()
                                                            .split(" ")[0];
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "mData" : function(data,
                                                        type, full) {
                                                    return data.city.city
                                                            + ", "
                                                            + data.address;
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "mData" : "priceCategory",
                                                "mRender" : function(data,
                                                        type, full) {
                                                    return data.priceCategory;
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "mData" : "website"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "mData" : function(data,
                                                        type, full) {
                                                    return data.owner.firstName
                                                            + " "
                                                            + data.owner.lastName;
                                                }
                                            } ]
                                });
                table
                        .on(
                                'draw',
                                function() {
                                    if (table.fnSettings().sAjaxSource
                                            .indexOf("all-events") > -1) {
                                        $(
                                                '.dropdown-menu>li>a:contains("Reject"),a:contains("Approve")')
                                                .hide();
                                    } else {
                                        $(
                                                '.dropdown-menu>li>a:contains("Refuse"),a:contains("Send Again")')
                                                .hide();
                                    }
                                });
                $("#request_table_obtain_length > label > select").change(
                        function() {
                            size = $(this).val();
                            showEvents();

                        });
            });
```

On my jsp I have drop down menu that helps me to choice how many elements I want to see on page. I take this parameter (size) and send it to me controller that requests two parameters. The main problem is how should I build paging field on jsp, and how the second paramter should be sent to controller (maybe with usage ajax or jQuery). Fragment of jsp with paging and drop down menu look like:

```
<div class="box-body table-responsive">
            <select id="request_table_obtain_length" class="dataTableDropDown">
                <option selected="selected" value="10">10</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>
                <option value="100">100</option>
            </select>
            <table id="request_table_obtain"
                class="table table-bordered table-striped">

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><spring:message code="label.eventTitle" /></th>
                        <th><spring:message code="label.startDate" /></th>
                        <th><spring:message code="label.location" /></th>
                        <th><spring:message code="label.price" /></th>
                        <th><spring:message code="label.website" /></th>
                        <th><spring:message code="label.organizer" /></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
            <div class="box-footer clearfix">
                <ul class="pagination pagination-sm no-margin pull-right">
                    <li><a href="#">«</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">»</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pagination"?  Do you mean that you want to have control of where the page breaks occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to track what page of the records is displayed.
You will also need navigation buttons (or links) for previous and next page.

The Next button will be displayed if there is more records to be displayed.
When this button is clicked you will send an ajax request for next page.

The Previous button will be displayed if current page is not the first one.
When this button is clicked you will send an ajax request for previous page.

Ultimately you can store loaded records in local array, and reference them instead calling the server each time for already visited page(s).

I have shown code for this functionality in similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28055425/4454454).